# SSE - (Sent server events)

Tags: javascript, php, json, server-sent-events

I'm using server-sent-events (SSE), I wanted it to update the same line, instead of creating another one with the same data, for example:
I am requesting SSE to update the data in real time (JSON), but instead of updating the data, it sends the same data on the line below;

```
**JSON (example):**

{"user": "John", "message": "First line"}
```

```
He returns me every 3 seconds:
user: John - message: first line
user: John - message: first line
user: John - message: first line
user: John - message: first line
(and so on, in an infinite loop).
```

**I wanted him to just update the same line;**

MY COMPLETE CODE:

- **Front**

```
**This code requests the SSE**
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Using Server-Sent Events</title>
<script>
    var source = new EventSource("test.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var jdata = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "" + event.data + "<br>";
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result">
        <!--Server response will be inserted here-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

- **Back**

```
**This code responds with JSON**
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
              CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.chat-api.com/instance****/messages?token=*****&chatId=*****%40c.us",
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
              CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
              CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Content-Type: application/json"
              ),
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $array = json_decode($response);

            foreach ($array->messages as $value) {
              $data = json_encode($value->body);
              echo "data: {$data}\n\n";
              flush();
            }


?>
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, Can you show us some code, we can't help you with the lack of information

Comment: Yes, of course:

https://prnt.sc/sxwzrz (This code requests the SSE) --------

https://prnt.sc/sxx1b4 (This code responds with JSON)

Comment: Its better to add your code in your question and not with a screenshot, but with tag

Comment: Done! It got better?

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

**test.php** -
Replace your echo by :

```
echo "<p id='dataresult'>data: {$data}\n\n</p>";
```

And in your **js script** :

```
  **This code requests the SSE**
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Using Server-Sent Events</title>
<script>
    var source = new EventSource("test.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var jdata = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "" + event.data + "<br>";
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result">
        <!--Server response will be inserted here-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's answer you question, dont forget to valid the answer and a little upvote ;)

Comment: Sorry, but I think it didn't work very well ...
The page (front-end) requests the JSON file to the back-end,when I added the:  echo" <p id = 'result'> data: {$ data} \ n \ n </p> "; on the back-end, it stopped sending data to the FRONT-END ---> Remembering that I'm using SSE to receive data in real time.

Comment: I edited my code, didnt see your div already have the id "result", if it dont work, try without the condition :
     if(getElementById("dataresult"))

Comment: It even worked, but it removes the value of "<p>" very quickly, so it turns out that you can't see the 'messages'.
I was using Ajax with setInterval, but it will be around 30 people using it, so I figured I would overload the machine and end up slowing down the application.

I was referred to the SSE, but it doesn't work as I expected, do you know any way?

Comment: Wht did you just dont do "=" instead of "+=" in your js script, i edited my answer

Comment: If I do without the "+ =", it goes like this: https://prnt.sc/sxz1q9
The correct way would be like this: https://prnt.sc/sxz191, only that it creates a looping and keeps copying the message infinitely

Comment: You have multiple message, you need to format a variable in your php with all your variable and after send it to your js,